# How to ignore a directory in a checkout without removing from the project?

Tags: svn, directory, tortoisesvn, ignore, svn-checkout

I have a svn project to keep several subdirectories (of course !).
Some of them are used just for local usage but must be saved in the repository.
However, on an other computer, we checkout the same project to release official versions. Of course, we checkout the parent directory of my famous subdirs... But they must not be included in the official release !

If I add this subdirs to the ignore list of Tortoise, they are removed from the repository ! I just want not to check it out without having to delete manually these subdirs or checking out a define list of subdirs.

Thanks a lot

Comment: To release official versions, I suggest you to perform either a checkout or an export command, followed by removing the useless subdirs (in local). Obviously you should put these commands in a script file.

Comment: That's what I do. I must checkout the project to update the repository. If I use a export command, it will update and add files, but it will not erase dirs or files. I can't delete the export directories, since I must add special files (not in SVN) used for the release... And each time I remove the unwanted sub-dir, SVN tells me the repository is not up to date... Argh !!